# Emulating step graphs using Infragistics XamChart

Tags: charts, infragistics

I need to have a step graph that looks like the black solid line in the image at the below link, using XamChart of Infragistics.

http://bloggpro.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/06/windowslivewriterstepcharttypeinexcel-2da1clip-image00231.gif

I have gone through several links, and the support for step graphs does not seem to be present in XamChart.
I feel this can be achieved using DataPoints and Markers on XamChart, but could not exactly get what I want.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to emulate a stepline chart would be to use a scatter line chart, and emit the extra points to create the stair stepping effect. This may not be wholly desired though depending on your needs for your labeling or tooltips, as you will be making it seem to the user as if extra data exists that is not strictly there. Also, if you needed the stepline series to coexist with category type series this would be made more difficult by using a scatter series to emulate the stepping effect.

Is it an option for you to use XamDataChart instead (probably included in your subscription)? XamDataChart does support a stepline type, natively.

Comment: Thanks for the response Graham.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Graham. 
Unfortunately using XamDataChart is not an option for me.
I cannot use a Scatter Chart either as I want the stepline series to be used along with column charts(non-scatter types).
I was thinking of using a Line chart with adding extra datapoints between two actual datapoints to make it work, but am stuck at getting the X/Y co-ordinates on the axes behind to manually add the extra datapoints.

Any help with a way out will be greatly appreciated.